# Every Python IDLE run starts a new process

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

Windows 7: I'm using Python3.2 with IDLE. Every time I edit and load my program, I get a new "pythonw.exe *32" process (as shown by Windows Task Manager)--even if the program just prints Hello World.

This is a special nuisance if the program is on a static RAM drive, because then I have to kill each of these processes individually before I can eject my drive.

Is this a bug in IDLE? Is there a way I can prevent this from happening? Or at least, is there a way I can kill all these pythonw processes at once, instead of one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to version 3.2.2.  That fixed the bug for me.  I saw the same thing in 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can also kill multiple python processes at once on Windows with the command:

```
taskkill /F /IM pythonw.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this on Windows 7, running IDLE v2.7.3; Tk version 8.5; Python 2.7.3

However, it only seems to fail to close the process if you kill a program before it finishes on its own.  If possible, let your programs run to their end.